# My Media queries work on my iphone but not on browser resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

When i view my site on my iphone, it all looks as i planned but however when i resize my browser to check css changes quicker, i can't see the media query making any effect on it.

My responsive design part of my CSS starts off as:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {

/*style*/

}
```

I then have the following in my head tag along with linking the stylesheet

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Can anyone help me out here? Thanks - www.joewinfield.net/portfolio

Comment: As far as im aware min-device-width & max are only taking the screen size of the device into account. Not the browser window. Try adding max-width : 320px  to take browser window sizes int account

Answer (score 3):

Use `min-width` in the media query instead of `min-device-width`. The same goes for `max-device-width`of course.

The `min-device-width` refers to the display's resolution (eg. the 1024 from 1024x768), while `min-width` refers to the width of the browser itself.

It is generally a better approach to use `min-width` instead of `min-device-width`.

Comment: It worked! that makes a lot of sense taking out the 'device' part. The smallest of things always catches out the coder. Thank you!